# how to make field integer constant by using php

Tags: php, mysql

am very new in php and I need your help,my question is! I have a table    payment with the following fields, which contain several values.

```
   id | idnumber | school_fee | fee_setting 
   1    v01        100          300           
   2    v02        50           0                              
   3    v03        150          0
```

What I want is to make each row of (fee_setting) field to have the same value of 300,so that to Subtract (school_fee) according to idnumber.
NOTE: idnumber is student idnumber and id is auto increament.
Example 300-100(v01), 300-50(v02), 300-150(v03).
Any body please help me, am stacking on this.

Comment: `update payment set fee_setting=300` ?

Comment: Or even better, eliminate the whole column since `fee_setting` will always be `==300`

Comment: But remember am using php, and one student can pay more than two time,

Comment: php appears only in a tag. The whole question is DB-oriented (_table, row, fields, autoincrement..._) Besides, your requirement was "_What I want is to make each row of (fee_setting) field to have the same value of 300_" all along!

Answer (score 1):

First issue a statement to your table like this

```
UPDATE table SET fee_setting=300 WHERE 1=1;
```

to change your fee_setting column to 300 as a default column. Now run this query to get your results.

```
SELECT ID,ROUND(fee_setting - school_fee) AS DIFF ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: Neither `WHERE 1=1` nor `ORDER BY ID` are required.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 UPDATE payment SET fee_setting=300;
```

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, for existing records you can do an "UPDATE", and for future records you can set the default value by altering the table as follows:

ALTER TABLE [your table name here] MODIFY fee_setting INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 300;

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default value in the database:

```
ALTER TABLE  `table ` CHANGE  `fee_setting`  `fee_setting` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '300'
```

You'll still have to alter existing records with the update statements listed in this thread.

But I agree with Geo, if this is always the same number why store it in the database at all?